# L'accord du participe passé

Tags: accord, participe-passé

Dans le cas de « faire » ou « laisser », si l'auxiliaire « être » est utilisé, est-ce qu'on l'accorde ?

Par exemple :

> Il avait été laissé seul dans la maison.

He was being left alone at home.

Comment: Il y a une incohérence entre votre question et l'exemple que vous donnez... Dans votre exemple l'auxiliaire est "avoir" et le verbe "être". De plus afin d'illustrer l'accord il conviendrait de prendre un exemple au fémninin, au pluriel, ou les 2, car dans votre cas il est impossible de savoir si "laissé" n'est pas accordé ou accordé avec le sujet masculin singulier...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oui, on accorde le participe passé au sujet, par exemple :

> elle est faite comme ça.
> elles sont laissées seules.

En l'occurrence il s'agit de la forme passive. Au passé composé, "faire" et "laisser" utilisent l'auxiliaire avoir:

> il a laissé de la mousse au chocolat.
> elles ont fait des crêpes.

Pour les verbes qui utilisent l'auxiliaire être au passé composé, on accorde également le participe passé au sujet:

> elle est partie chez sa tante.
> elles sont allées chez leur grand-mère.

Par contre lorsque le verbe utilise l'auxiliaire avoir, la règle est compliquée: on accorde le participe passé avec le complément d'objet *uniquement* lorsque celui-ci précède le verbe:

> la mousse au chocolat qu'il a laissée.
>
> les crêpes qu'elle a faites.

Notez cependant que les règles du français oral évoluent très rapidement. Les gens accordent de moins en moins les participes et même les adjectifs.

PS: pourquoi cette règle si compliquée? Apparemment les grammairiens du XVIIe siècle ont tenté de calquer les règles sur l'Italien, par snobisme latinisant. Mais ils n'ont pas bien compris la règle en Italien :)

Comment: N'oublions pas le subtil "verbe conjugué + verbe à l'infinitif": "Les crêpes qu'elle a faites" MAIS "Les crêpes qu'elle a fait faire". De plus sauf erreur la non-accord des participe et à fortiori des adjectifs est et reste une erreur. Que de plus en plus de gens ne s'embarassent plus de ça ne change rien, cela veut juste dire que de plus en plus de gens ne connaissent pas cette règle de base de la grammaire. S'il y a effectivement débat sur l'accord du participe passé, il est loin d'être clos.